# Labeling tick marks in script style and putting arrowheads on line using addplot command

Tags: pgfplots

The code provided instructs TikZ to plot the graph for y = (x^{2} - 4)/(x + 2). There are several modifications needed. The graph looks like the line y = x - 2. How do I get arrowheads at both ends of the graph of this function?

How do I get the label $x$ on the x-axis positioned below and slightly to the right of the right arrowhead, and how do I get the label $y$ on the y-axis positioned above and slightly to the right of the top arrowhead?  How do I get the tickmark "-2" typeset in `scriptstyle` and in a white box - I don't want the dashed line between points (-2,0) and (-2,-4) drawn over it.  How do I shorten the y-axis?  It is drawn too low.

I have two commands in the code for the axes: `xmax=8,ymax=7` and `restrict y to domain=-7:10`.  What do they instruct TikZ to draw?  Why aren't there `xmin` and `ymin` commands?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\begin{document}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image,
          xmax=8,ymax=7,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-7:7,
          enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
          axis line style={latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          ytick=\empty,
          xtick={-2}
          %xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
]
\addplot[domain=-10:10,mark=none,samples=10] {x - 2} node [above left, yshift=3pt]{$\scriptstyle{y}=\frac{x^{\scriptscriptstyle{2}} - 4}{x + 2}$};
\draw [thin,dashed] (-2,0) -- (-2,-4);
\draw [fill=white] (-2,-4) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[left]{$\scriptstyle{(-2, \, -4)}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you just draw `x-2`? Just expand the quadratic no?

Comment: I did. That didn't give me any of the modifications for which I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

You must have figured this out by now, but in case anyone else sees this and wonders.

- **Arrowheads**: same method as you used for the axes essentially, add `<->` to the `\addplot` options.
- **Position of axis labels**: change the anchors with

  ```
  xlabel style={anchor=north west},
  ylabel style={anchor=south west}
  ```
- **Ticklabel font size**: add `font=\scriptsize` to the `ticklabel style`.
- **Ticklabel below line**: simple way is to add `axis on top` to the `axis` options.
- `xmin`/`ymin`: I don't understand why you say those keys don't exist. They do. And setting `ymin` is how you would shorten the y-axis.
- **`restrict y to domain`**: does exactly what it says I think, it filters out y-values outside the given domain.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
          axis on top, % added
          axis equal image,
          xmax=8,ymax=7,
          xmin=-3,ymin=-4,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-7:7,
          enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
          axis line style={latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white,font=\scriptsize}, % added font
          ytick=\empty,
          xtick={-2},
          xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
          xlabel style={anchor=north west}, % added
          ylabel style={anchor=south west}, % added
]
\addplot[domain=-10:10,mark=none,samples=10,<->] {x - 2} node [above left, yshift=3pt]{$\scriptstyle{y}=\frac{x^{\scriptscriptstyle{2}} - 4}{x + 2}$};
\draw [thin,dashed] (-2,0) -- (-2,-4);
\draw [fill=white] (-2,-4) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[left]{$\scriptstyle{(-2, \, -4)}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```